# How can I grant access to a remote git repo?

Tags: git

There is a project where I have access to a remote git repo where I have been deploying my changes for years, but the address is my sole information. Now, a new guy should be able to access it, but I do not know how should I grant him access. Google search yielded some results in GitHub, but this is command-line and the guy who granted me access a long while ago is no longer in the team. Is there a way to grant access to the new guy to the repo I am using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found out the answer in the meantime:

```
1. ssh <path or alias>
2. vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. Add the public ssh key.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep! There is actually a couple well-known easy ways to do so. I'll state here two. Just one thing to note is that the authorization is related to the server and not git! Meaning, the solution I'm discussing here is all about creating user (or using pre-existing user) and passing the access credentials to your guy.

**Solution A**

Create a new user on the server and pass the username and password to the guy. He'll then be able to clone the rep:

```
git clone username@hostname:/path/to/.git
```

It's prompted then to enter the password. He's then good to go. You will create a new user for every new *guy* will work with. The up point here is that this is an easy and good solution for small teams. This gets really bad if the team gets bigger!

**Solution B**

Create a new user on the server or use an existent one and pass out the username to every *guy* will be using the git repo, even yourself if you want! Just make sure that every one you want to grant access to sends you his/her public key like so:

On the *guy's* side:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This should generate a private and a public key-pair. He should send you the public one (the one with .pub extension). You take the file and do the following:

```
sh-copy-id [-i fileName] userName@host
```

The `username` is the username you are passing out to every *guy*. The host name is the server's host name. You execute this command from your local machine. (This is equivalent to the commands you are posting in your answer)

Just make to shutdown the bash shell for that user so that you guarantee that no user will ssh the server :D here's how to do so: (you execute this command on your server machine)

```
sudo chsh username # and enter the path to git-shell, usually: /usr/bin/git-shell
```

The up point here is that this is really easy method when team extends.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer, however, the answer does not really apply to my particular case, as I am adding an already existent user. Using the very same user for a whole team seems like a bad idea, since you cannot use git blame, for instance. I will upvote your answer though, but cannot accept it.

Comment: git blame has nothing to do with the server authorization. git blame uses the git configuration set up by every user with the command `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`.

Comment: joker, it has. If you use the very same user with aliases, nothing prevents users from changing their aliases. Different git users are needed for different real users to be able to easily differentiate them even if they do not want to be differentiated. And my question was about authorizing a user. Both your solutions involve the creation of at least a git user, so you assume that the user who joined does not already have a git user, or would use "our" git user. I prefer to allow people use their well-established identity, which is out of your answer's scope.

Comment: And how can you differentiate between logs submitted by different users logged into the server with different users credentials but have the same username configured in git using `git config user.name`?

Comment: Good question. I am not sure how, but it should be possible.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot! hence, the solution is totally fine.

Comment: If you do not know about something, then it not necessarily does not exist. If you know that there is no way, that's a different question. However, your solution is not perfect, since it always implies the creation of a new user, regardless of whether there is a need for one.

Comment: Let us gather knowledge about our debate. I have asked a question here for that purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331961/how-to-differentiate-two-git-users-who-happen-to-have-the-same-config

Comment: That's great. One more thing to point out that might not be clear in my solution. Solution B, you don't have to create a new one. You can use existing user and perform the rest of the solution.

Comment: Right, the idea of solution B is to share a user, one can start with an existing one. I have edited your answer to make this clear for future visitors.