# How to differentiate two git users who happen to have the same config?

Tags: git

Let us suppose that there are two different git users, U1 and U2. Let's suppose further that they have the same config, for example their

```
git config user.name
```

is the very same, but their public key is different. If one of them makes a commit, is there a way to tell which one of them made that commit?

Comment: Assuming email addresses are the same as well: Not directly. If they *sign* (`-S` GPG sign, not just `-s` sign) the commit, and have different GPG keys, you can tell one from another.

Comment: @torek, can you elaborate about GPG keys?

Comment: Check [here](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work).

Comment: It's a big topic, you might start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard for an overview. The general idea is to create a digital signature using encryption algorithms that allow users with some kind of shared trust to verify the identity of other users. Bootstrapping the trust mechanism is critical to making it all work, and complications come in with trust revocation (when someone's secret key is exposed, for instance).

Comment: @raina77ow, thanks, it is a very useful article.

Comment: @torek, I will read the article, but I wonder whether a user can see another's GPG signature and use it. Maybe it also has a private key for authentication purposes.

Comment: Do you mean something different from `git log --show-signature`? (I suppose it should work the same way with `git show`)

Comment: The signatures use key-pairs (private and public keys). You must know public keys for users U1 and U2, which you use to verify a digital signature. Some of the theory is beyond me (I understand basic RSA but not elliptic curve functions), but there is more information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature (and yes, in terms of usage, it's `git log --show-signature` to verify the digital signature)

Comment: @torek, thanks for the insight. If you convert your ideas into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @LajosArpad I've been asleep, so you might as well use your own answer. The only thing I'd add to it is that in practice, most projects seem to sign only annotated tags (using the same encrypted signature methods) attached to release version and then rely on the Merkle tree structure of tag->commit->(everything) to use that to cover the release version and all history leading up to that point.

Comment: @torek, I am sorry I did not wait enough. Thank you for all the fantastic insight you have given. I hope this page will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was inspired by @Torek's comments. In fact, there is a possibility to use PGP sign and expect its usage of every developer accessing the repo. The PGP signature should be unique per user and as far as I understand, it can be pretty secure, as it uses a [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). If the users use [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to sign their commits, then they can be identified by the said public key even if their name and email appears to be equal. More info [here](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard).

EDIT:

"in practice, most projects seem to sign only annotated tags (using the same encrypted signature methods) attached to release version and then rely on the [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) structure of tag->commit->(everything) to use that to cover the release version and all history leading up to that point."

@torek, 2016-09-06

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not completely solve your problem, but I believe it has merit and over the long term would avoid what you are seeing.

By typing `git log`, you will see each commit listed with something like this:

```
commit f2a238924e89ca1d4947662928218a06d39068c3
Author: U1 <U1a@yourcompany.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 5 17:30:28 2014 -0500

    Comment goes here

 SomeClass.java | 42 ++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------
 1 file changed, 38 insertion(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

Even though they might have the same user names, if their *emails* are different, then you could still easily tell the commits apart.  So if your organization enforces that a) all users list their work email in the Git account, and b) the organization enforces unique email for everyone, then this problem will never happen.

Comment: This is a completely theoretical question, where I assume that name and email is similar. This question arised from a debate at an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310094/how-can-i-grant-access-to-a-remote-git-repo/39314982?noredirect=1#comment65984271_39314982

Comment: Then see the comment by @torek, who knows basically everything about Git.

Comment: Yes, Tim, indeed, he seems to be pretty knowledgable about git. I liked your answer though :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: definitely not *everything*, Git is a fairly big topic too. :-)